# Left sidebar menu which can open external link in the current menu page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm searching code to create 2 vertical sections: section on the left side with a vertical menu, section on the right side should have the content, which should be external (e.g. yahoo.com) . Section on the right should open an external (using the link in the left sections) and show at the same time the vertical menu in left section.

I found this https://colorlib.com/etc/bootstrap-sidebar/sidebar-02/ , however if I put an external link, link is opened in a new browser page without the vertical menu.

Any suggestion to reach this?

Comment: To "include" external website you need to use `<iframe>`. To change the iframe content, you need to change the src attribute of your iframe. You can do it with JS.

Comment: Thank you , may I see an example because I can't really find an example.

Comment: On top of the iframe's documentation page from Mozilla : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe